# Logging SOAP errors in Mule ESB

Tags: logging, soap, error-handling, mule

I'm trying to get Mule to log the exception that my SOAP component throws in the following flow. For instance, if I pass it malformed xml as an input, in soapUI I get a meaningful output, but I want to be able to log this in either the console or to send it to a JMS queue.

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<flow name="CAB-Mule_WMBFlow1" doc:name="CAB-Mule_WMBFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8081/DemoCustomer" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/xml">
        <idempotent-redelivery-policy maxRedeliveryCount="3">
            <dead-letter-queue> 
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="error-queue" /> 
            </dead-letter-queue>
        </idempotent-redelivery-policy>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <cxf:jaxws-service port="80" serviceClass="com.mulesoft.demo.DemoCustomer" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    <component class="com.mulesoft.demo.DemoCustomerIntImpl" doc:name="Java"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="StudioIN" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Payload: #[payload]"/>
</flow>
<flow name="error" doc:name="error">
    <component class="com.mulesoft.demo.ExceptionService" doc:name="Java"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="Error" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
</flow>
```

ExceptionService is just:

```
public class ExceptionService {
    public void onException(ExceptionMessage e) {
        System.err.println("EXCEPTION MESSAGE:::: " + e.getException().getMessage());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a `<catch-exception-strategy>` before the `CAB-Mule_WMBFlow1` ends like this and log and push the error message to JMS queue

```
<flow name="CAB-Mule_WMBFlow1" doc:name="CAB-Mule_WMBFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8081/DemoCustomer" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/xml">
        <idempotent-redelivery-policy maxRedeliveryCount="3">
            <dead-letter-queue> 
                <vm:outbound-endpoint path="error-queue" /> 
            </dead-letter-queue>
        </idempotent-redelivery-policy>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <cxf:jaxws-service port="80" serviceClass="com.mulesoft.demo.DemoCustomer" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    <component class="com.mulesoft.demo.DemoCustomerIntImpl" doc:name="Java"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="StudioIN" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Payload: #[payload]"/>

    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <logger level="INFO" message="---->Exception payload is: #[payload]"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="Error" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Additionally, you may use `message.getExceptionPayload().getMessage()` to get the exception message in java component and print it on console where message is of type `MuleMessage`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me, I don't get the logger message to console and the Error queue doesn't get any messages either. Do I have to set a global exception strategy too?